# powertoys Windows 7 replacement

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, command-line

I'm looking for PowerToys for Windows 7, does anyone know where I can find the "Open Command Window Here" thingy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Open Command Window Here" functionality is now built in.

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> then right click over the folder. The "Command prompt" option should now appear on the context menu.

*I can't double check the exact wording of the option as I'm back using XP at the moment*

Comment: It works that way for Vista.  There are also other Shift-click options, such as "copy file path".  I believe that 7 also has more "Send To" options when you use the shift key.

Comment: @Daniel - I managed to bypass Vista ;)

Answer (score 6):

There are no longer any "Official" Power Toys.

The `Open Command Windows Here` option is there by default if you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> whilst right clicking on a folder.

However, to add the `Open Command Window Here` context menu without having to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>, do the following:

1. Open up the Registry Editor (Press <kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `Regedit`)
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd`
3. Delete the "REG_SZ" entry called "Extended"

(You can also repeat this for the entry at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\drive\shell\cmd`)

It should now appear.

Answer (score 1):

The Powertoys provided additional functionality for Windows XP...Some are redundant with Windows 7. You can hold the SHIFT key and right-click a folder, and the command window option will appear. That's a little bother, though, having to hold SHIFT.

If you download and use Ultimate Windows Tweaker, you have access to a good number of options for tweaking Win7 appearance and behaviour. One option is to make the command window option appear on right-click without having to hold the SHIFT key. There a lot of other useful options as well.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10, it has been replaced with Open Powershell window here. To get Open Command window here back, go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\cmd, then take ownership of the key, and then Change the DWORD name from HideBasedOnVelocityId to ShowBasedOnVelocityId.